# R regex - extract words beginning with @ symbol

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm trying to extract twitter handles from tweets using R's [stringr package](https://github.com/tidyverse/stringr). For example, suppose I want to get all words in a vector that begin with "A". I can do this like so

```
library(stringr)

# Get all words that begin with "A"
str_extract_all(c("hAi", "hi Ahello Ame"), "(?<=\\b)A[^\\s]+")

[[1]]
character(0)

[[2]]
[1] "Ahello" "Ame"
```

Great. Now let's try the same thing using "@" instead of "A"

```
str_extract_all(c("h@i", "hi @hello @me"), "(?<=\\b)\\@[^\\s]+")

[[1]]
[1] "@i"

[[2]]
character(0)
```

Why does this example give the opposite result that I was expecting and how can I fix it?

Comment: `@` is not a *word* character, thus you cannot use `\b` (because it splits your words)

Comment: In case you have cases like `hi,@ann` you will need an unambiguous word boundary, see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55172527/3832970).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you probably mean

```
str_extract_all(c("h@i", "hi @hello @me", "@twitter"), "(?<=^|\\s)@[^\\s]+")
# [[1]]
# character(0)
# [[2]]
# [1] "@hello" "@me" 
# [[3]]
# [1] "@twitter"
```

The `\b` in a regular expression is a boundary and it occurs "Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character." [see here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). Since an space and "@" are both non-word characters, there is no boundary before the "@".

With this revision you match either the start of the string or values that come after spaces.

Comment: As a side-note, I think `(?<=\\b)` (from OP's original) is equivalent to `\\b`, since the match will not include the boundary change. However, in the solution the positive look-behind is indeed needed since we do not want the space to be part of the match.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of things about your regex:

- `(?<=\b)` is the same as `\b` because a word boundary is already a zero width assertion
- `\@` is the same as `@`, as `@` is not a special regex metacharacter and you do not have to escape it
- `[^\s]+` is the same as `\S+`, almost all shorthand character classes have their negated counterparts in regex.

So, your regex, `\b@\S+`, matches `@i` in `h@i` because there is a word boundary between `h` (a letter, a word char) and `@` (a non-word char, not a letter, digit or underscore). Check [this **regex debugger**](https://regex101.com/r/aNAayy/1/debugger).

**`\b` is an ambiguous pattern whose meaning depends on the regex context**. In your case, you might want to use `\B`, a non-word boundary, that is, `\B@\S+`, and it will match `@` that are either preceded with a non-word char or at the start of the string.

```
x <- c("h@i", "hi @hello @me")
regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\B@\\S+", x))
## => [[1]]
## character(0)
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "@hello" "@me"
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/aNAayy/2).

If you want to get rid of this `\b`/`\B` ambiguity, use unambiguous word boundaries using lookarounds with stringr methods or base R regex functions with `perl=TRUE` argument:

```
regmatches(x, gregexpr("(?<!\\w)@\\S+", x, perl=TRUE))
regmatches(x, gregexpr("(?<!\\S)@\\S+", x, perl=TRUE))
```

where:

- `(?<!\w)` - **an unambiguous starting word boundary** - is a negative lookbehind that makes sure there is a non-word char immediately to the left of the current location or start of string
- `(?<!\S)` -  **a whitespace starting word boundary** - is a negative lookbehind that makes sure there is a whitespace char immediately to the left of the current location or start of string.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aNAayy/3) and [another regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/aNAayy/4).

Note that the corresponding right hand boundaries are `(?!\w)` and `(?!\S)`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above should suffice.  This will remove the @ symbol in case you are trying to get the users' names only.

```
str_extract_all(c("@tweeter tweet", "h@is", "tweet @tweeter2"), "(?<=\\B\\@)[^\\s]+")
[[1]]
[1] "tweeter"

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
[1] "tweeter2"
```

While I am no expert with regex, it seems like the issue may be that the @ symbol does not correspond to a word character, and thus matching the empty string at the beginning of a word (`\\b`) does not work because there is no empty string when @ is preceding the word.

Here are two great regex resources in case you hadn't seen them:

- [stat545](http://stat545.com/block022_regular-expression.html)
- [Stringr's Regex page](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html), also available as a vignette:

  `vignette("regular-expressions", package = "stringr")`

Comment: This seems to also grab the "i" in "h@i" which the OP was trying to avoid,

Comment: You're absolutely right, I missed that.  I updated it now.