# displaying all vectors without the given character (#)

Tags: r, regex

I know that there is a similar topic on the forum, but there is no answer to my question, and I tried in different ways ([R regex - extract words beginning with @ symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55171086/r-regex-extract-words-beginning-with-symbol)). I need to write out all words that do not have a symbol in front of them.

Below is a code that cuts out all words that contain the #sign and the result of this action.

```
tweeter <- c("#tweeter tweet", "h#is", "tweet #tweeter2", "twet")
str_extract_all(tweeter, "(?<=\\B\\#)[^\\s]+")
```

Result of it:

```
[[1]]
[1] "tweeter"

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
[1] "tweeter2"

[[4]]
character(0)
```

Now the code with which he tries to display all the words without # at the beginning.

```
regmatches(tweeter, gregexpr("\\B#\\S+", tweeter), invert = T)
```

I would like to display a list of words that don't start with #just don't know how to write it properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gives you words that doesn't begin with `#`

```r
library(stringr)

tweeter[!str_detect(tweeter, "^#")]
# "h#is"            "tweet #tweeter2" "twet"
```

## Explanation

`str_detect(tweeter, "^#")` returns a logical vector based on the `pattern` and in this case `^#`. `^` matches the beginning and `#` specifies the character to match at the beginning.

Finally, to return values where the condition is `TRUE` we use `tweeter[]`.

The same thing can be achieved without using `!` which negates the logical value by using `negate` argument within the `str_detect` as follows:

```r
tweeter[str_detect(tweeter, "^#", negate = TRUE)]
# "h#is"            "tweet #tweeter2" "twet"
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, we can use `grep` with `invert` and `value` parameter as `TRUE`.

```
grep("^#", tweeter, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
#[1] "h#is"            "tweet #tweeter2" "twet"
```