# Selecting multiple entries based on a certain criteria from the dataframe with a lot of junk text in R

Tags: r, dataframe, text, data.table, selection

I have a huge dataframe of thousands of rows imported from the .csv file. Although the text inside is comma separated, R recognizes the imported dataframe as a single column (my guess is - due to its overcomplicated and irregular structure). I want to search every row for any string carrying @ symbol (like @marine, @tested etc.) and put all of them into another column. Unfortunately, the rows are of different length.

Here's what I have (2 rows example):

```
"254,""CC4qoAPgs0p"",""_ohc=l5OM-bXL0z4AX_eH6id&oh=246b0f63e5f90a14f28e0f9e40989372&oe=5F402F36"",""8"",""26793924834"",""How do you relax at night after a long day working? #doterra #doterraessentialoils @aromatherapy #essentialoils @terra #healthandwellness @terra @doterraoils2 #vegan #healthy #stressfree, 254a

"255,""DC4qDVhJRYH"",""_ohc=52ns_Li8iNQAX9wNlw6&oh=5c6b7f2193799aa6755b67ea6acec857&oe=5F41C4CA"",""12"",""37345461877""," "<U+0001F4F2> https://wa.me/60169573359  Anis Nadzirah Shaklee Independent Distributor Kuala @Berang  @shaklee %shaklee%lover, 255a
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
number       tags
254         @aromatherapy
            @terra
            @terra
            @doterraoils2

255         @Berang
            @shaklee
```

I tried to do this with data.table package

```
library(data.table)
section <-  df[rownames(a) %like% "@", ]
```

but got rather strange results, out of 10K rows it created me only 27.
Can somebody help me with this?
thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you import the data? Can you share your code?

Comment: @Paul van Oppen  Sure, I use this simple one row code:                                         df <- read.csv("input_mess.csv", sep = ";") , where input_mess.csv is my original file.    It works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes are getting in the way and need to be removed. Then you need some regex to extract the terms that start with `@`.
This should get you on your way: I use `readLines` to read the data and use `stringr::str_replace_all` to get rid of all the quotes. The first `lapply` extracts words starting with `@` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55171086/r-regex-extract-words-beginning-with-symbol)) and the second lapply extracts the `number`. We then need to combine things into a data frame. This can probably be further simplified.

```
library(stringr)

data <- readLines("data_with_quotes.csv")
data <- str_replace_all(string = data, pattern = "\"", replacement  = "")

l <- lapply(data, FUN = function(x) str_extract_all(x, "(?<=^|\\s)@[^\\s]+"))
h <- lapply(data, FUN = function(x) str_sub(x, start = 1, end = 3))

df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(l), nrow = length(l), byrow = T))
row.names(df) <- unlist(h)
```

With this output:

```
> df
               X1      X2       X3
254 @aromatherapy  @terra   @terra
255 @doterraoils2 @Berang @shaklee
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seem to work. Appreciate your quick help.